# scp returns No such file or directory in script but executes when run manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting, scp

For context, I need to use a custom command to build an identity file so I can ssh successfully. I've renamed it because it's an internal tool and want to avoid NDA issues. You can consider it as a block box that builds and executes an ssh to a remote host. If I run the bash function, the scp command fails, but when I run the built scp command manually, it executes successfully.

```bash
scp-from-station() {
    # A string representation of the CustomCommand command you would use to access the station you want to SCP onto
    set -x
    pwd
    echo $USER
    custom_command="$1"
    source_path="$2"
    destination_path="$3"

    unset ip_address
    unset identity_file
    unset ssh_string

    output="$(exit | $custom_command)"

    if [[ "$output" == "Midway token has expired - run \`mwinit --aea -o\`" ]] || [[ "$output" == *"Job execution failed!"* ]]; then
      echo "Must first run 'mwinit'"
      mwinit
      output="$(exit | $custom_command)"
    fi

    ssh_string=${output#*Attempting log in... Executing: }

    ip_address=$(echo $ssh_string | grep -Eo "(\d+.){3}(\d)+$")
    identity_file=$(echo $ssh_string | grep -Eo "~\/.ssh\/id_rsa_.* ")
    scp_command="scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $identity_file -r ${USER}@${ip_address}:${source_path} ${destination_path}"
#    echo "running $scp_command"
    $("$scp_command")
    set +x
}
```

I run `scp-from-station "CustomCommand --option arugment" /tmp/Logs.tar.gz /Users/myuser/Downloads`

The scp command when run in the script returns  `bash: scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_134114a8-7b25-11ed-8f47-acde48001122 -r myuser@10.160.89.93:/tmp/Logs.tar.gz /Users/myuser/Downloads: No such file or directory`

But when I run it manually, it scp's the file successfully.

I've done sanity checks for the working directory and the present working directory, but no luck. The username on the remote machine is the same as my local one.

Comment: You have `$scp_command` in double-quotes, which is good when you want to copy the contents of the variable for processing, but not as good when the variable contains a command and (space-separated) arguments to be executed by the shell.  The command substitution also isn't helping here, IMO.  How does it do if you change the line to just `$scp_command` with no double quotes or `$( ... )` command substitution?

Comment: Thanks. Using the scp command directly without doubles quotes fixes the issue: `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_134114a8-7b25-11ed-8f47-acde48001122 ...`

Initially I wanted to print the scp command so I wrote it as a string. I could just surround the scp command with a pair of `set -x, set +x`.

Comment: or you can have one line `echo "$scp_command"` (prints the command and args but doesn't execute them) followed by the next line `$scp_command` (executes the command and args but doesn't print them)

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention I also wanted the return number from scp so I can do some error handling, hence why I tried executing the command with `$(...)`

Comment: If you want the return code from `scp`, you can capture it with something like `scp_exit=$?` and test/print the code that's in `$scp_exit`.  You have to save the exit code into the variable as the very next statement in your script.  Any other statements in between can change the value in `$?` so it doesn't reflect the status from `scp` anymore.

Comment: Oh true. Thanks again. I understand, I've used that before, it references to the exit code for the last command executed.